# Justificar texto com TextAlignment no Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, xaml, windows-phone-8-1

Estou fazendo uma aplicação e nessa aplicação tenho um `textBlock` que no *.xaml* está da seguinte maneira:

```
 <TextBlock Name="tDetalhes"  Foreground="Black" FontSize="26" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="210"  TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Porem quero deixar o texto desta `textBlock` justificado, mas eu fui adicionar a propriedade `TextAlignment="Justify"` da o seguinte erro:

> "Specified method is not supported"

Tentei adicionar pelo código *.cs* e também não foi. Se alguém souber solucionar o erro ficarei grato. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como a mensagem diz, o `Justify` não é suportado no `textBlock`. Segundo [está página](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textalignment(v=vs.95).aspx) da MSDN esse valor não é válido no Silverlight 3.

Como alternativa, pode ser utilizado o controle [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Qual a propriedade que eu uso para add o texto? pq .text nao aparece como opção ?!

Comment: @DiegoLeite Já olhou [esse exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.95).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-4)?.